# Deploying a SpringBoot - Angular application to digitalocean

Tags: angular, spring-boot, tomcat, digital-ocean

I have a website running on my local machine and I want to deploy this application to DigitalOcean. I created a droplet, installed necessary things. My angular application starts when I enter server's ip adress:

http://138.68.76.62

Also I can run my spring boot app on tomcat. But these two don't run synchronously. When I run spring app on the local machine, remote angular app connnect it and work well. But I want to run it with remote spring application.

```
@RequestMapping("/token")
public Map<String,String> token (HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request){
    System.out.println(request.getRemoteHost());

    String remoteHost= request.getRemoteHost();
    int portNumber = request.getRemotePort();

    System.out.println(remoteHost+":"+portNumber);
    System.out.println(request.getRemoteAddr());

    return Collections.singletonMap("token",session.getId());
}
```

This is requestmapping for login.

```
@Injectable()
export class LoginService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  sendCredential(username: string, password: string) {
    let url = "http://localhost:8181/token";
    let encodedCredentials = btoa(username+":"+password);
    let basicHeader = "Basic "+encodedCredentials;
    let headers = new Headers ({
        'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization' : basicHeader
    });

    return this.http.get(url, {headers: headers});

 }
```

And this is the function for login in angular app.

Should I change http://localhost:8181/token to something like http://138.68.76.62:8181/token ?

Answer (score 0):

Just change it to `/`

```
@Injectable()
export class LoginService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  sendCredential(username: string, password: string) {
    let url = "/token";
    let encodedCredentials = btoa(username+":"+password);
    let basicHeader = "Basic "+encodedCredentials;
    let headers = new Headers ({
        'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization' : basicHeader
    });

    return this.http.get(url, {headers: headers});

 }
```

Comment: I edited the code as you said but there is no change. There is no response from server but works well with local server running.

Comment: is your angular app in the static folder of your Spring Boot application ?

Comment: No it is not. I run angular app with "ng serve" seperately from spring app. I uploaded dist folder generetated by ng build to /var/www/html folder

Comment: Ah ok. So you have to use localhost in the url. And verify your server logs and the browser console. May be you have a CORS problem.

Comment: I deployed my app's war file to tomcat on server. It runs but how can I make requests to it?
http://138.68.76.62:8080/bookstore-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/
This is the app link but in application.properties file port number is 8181.
I don't understand whether I should use default tomcat port 8080 or can I run an app on a different port?

Comment: It depend on whether you are using an embedded tomcat or not. For debugging, create a fat jar with a embedded tomcat. Put the server port to 8181 and launch it with a java -jar and test you application. if it works, then you have a problem in configuring you tomcat server.

Comment: Hi again, now I successfully deployed war file to tomcat. The error was I didn't add method for stating war application

     @Override
     protected SpringApplicationBuilder 
    configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
      return 
    application.sources(BookstoreAngularApplication.class);
     }
I can consume apis with URL but tomcat doesn't show index.html file located in static folder. It only displays a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

Use relative path and "/"

Example :

Absolute path:

```
 let url = "http://localhost:8181/token";
```

Relative path:

```
let url = "/token";
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you well they cant run simultaneously. Had the same problem if that is your problem and I realised the problem was with how I started Springboot in the server. If you run it from the target folder with java -jar and the name of your. I know this is late but may help some one

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).